# Override Material UI Expansion Panel Summary

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

```
expansionPanelSummary: {
        content: {
            "& > :last-child": {
                paddingRight: 0
            }
        },
        expandIcon: {
            top: "80%"
        }
    }
```

I am trying override the styles of Material UI Expansion Panel Component but not able to get results

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon color="primary" />}
                    classes={{ content: classes.expansionPanelSummary.content, expandIcon: classes.expansionPanelSummary.expandIcon}}
                >
```

I cannot override it on a theme level as this component is being used elsewhere with default settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have put an extra level ("expansionPanelSummary") into your `styles` object. That is not valid. The top level properties on the `styles` object passed to `withStyles` are what will be turned into classes. In your example, `classes.expansionPanelSummary` would have a value that is a classname generated by JSS, but `classes.expansionPanelSummary.content` would not.

Here's an example of the syntax needed:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const styles = {
  expansionPanelSummaryContent: {
    "& > :last-child": {
      paddingRight: 100
    }
  },
  expansionPanelSummaryExpandIcon: {
    top: "80%"
  }
};

function SimpleExpansionPanel(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          classes={{
            content: classes.expansionPanelSummaryContent,
            expandIcon: classes.expansionPanelSummaryExpandIcon
          }}
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>
            Expansion Panel 1 - increasing the amount of content so that I can
            tell a difference when the padding-right is altered.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleExpansionPanel);
```

I changed the `paddingRight` to 100 just so I could easily see an effect to verify it was being applied.

Here it is in a CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit ExpansionPanelSummary]